# Just curious about log4net log details

Tags: c#, log4net

Am using Log4Net to log my application,everything works fine to me, just wanna understand little bit more about the log details.

Here is my log:

```
2012-05-22 17:11:44,602 **[11]** ERROR Shell Exists - ignoreThe remote server returned an erro:
2012-05-29 15:48:11,876 **[32]** ERROR Shell Exists - ignoreThe remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).
```

Here is my config:

```xml
<appender name="ErrorAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <file value="c:\Error.log"/>
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <param name="LevelMin" value="ERROR"/>
    <param name="LevelMax" value="ERROR"/>
  </filter>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-2p %c %method - %m%n"/>
  </layout>
```

Just want to know what is **[11] or [32]** in my log file after time stamp, what it refers here ? hope some one will update my knowledge.

Comment: edited my answer, the [%t] is the threadid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That will totally depend on what pattern you provided.

But the default pattern has a [%thread], and that refers to the thread id.

This is what the pattern in many examples looks like:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
   <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

That [%t] is the thread id, alright.

Comment: Thanks nunespascal, i missed the conversion pattern.Thanks again.